# Convolution of $|x|^2$ and $\delta_S$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, convolution, dirac-delta

I am asked to give the convolution of $|x|^2$ and $\delta_S$, where $\delta_S$ is the simple layer on the sphere $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x|=1 \}$. But, my main problem is that I d'ont understand the meaning of this convolution. Do I need to integrate $|x|^2$ on the unit sphere?

Comment: You have two measures: $ |x|^2 \mathrm{d}x $ and $ \delta_S $.  You should begin by writing down the formula for the convolution of two measures.

Comment: Which will give me $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |x|^2 \delta_S(y-x) dx$, but what am i supposed to do from now on?

Comment: But, I can rewrite it as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |y-x|^2 \delta_S(x) dx = \int_{S} |y-x|^2 dS_{x} $. Am i wrong?

Comment: No, you seem to be very much right.  So you are integrating $ |y-x|^2 $ on the unit sphere, with respect to $ x $.  Do you want any hints on how to calculate this integral?

Comment: Please, it would be helpful. But, here $|y-x|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{3} (y_i-x_i)^2$ so I bet that it would be easier to integrate in polar coordinates right?

Comment: Try to leverage symmetry.  Start with $ |y-x|^2 = (y-x)\cdot(y-x) = y \cdot y - 2 x \cdot y + x \cdot x = |y|^2 + |x|^2 - 2 x \cdot y $.  This allows you to split into three easy (easier) integrals.  $ |y|^2 $ is a constant (very easy), $ |x|^2 $ is also a constant (on the sphere, at least), and this leaves you with the $ x \cdot y $ term.  Think about what the dot product means.  I claim this integral of $ x \cdot y $ has a clear value if you think about the picture.

Comment: Right, $|y|^2$ is a constant since we are integrating over $S_x$ and $|x|^2 = 1$ on $S$ so that's why it is a constant, am I wrong? Plus, $x⋅y = |y| |x| cos(\theta) =  |y| cos(\theta)$ over $S$, so I only need to consider $cos(\theta)$ while integrating.

Comment: That's good, but before you start calculating, think about symmetry.  The answer is obvious if you think about what it means to integrate $\cos(\theta)$ on a sphere.

Comment: Oh you're right, it's only $0$ since I'm considering $cos(\theta)$ on its period.